# How do I get the contents within HTML tags of certain attributes (e.g., colspan) using the Ruby gem Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Here's an example of the HTML:

```
<td colspan="3">TARGET</td>
<td>NOT TARGET</td>
```

How do I use Ruby's Mechanize gem to target only the `<td>` with  `colspan="3"`?

Comment: The what?  'to target only the ___ with"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanize relies on the HTML/XML parser [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to handle its heavy lifting.

Typically we use `agent` as the variable for Mechanize. Testing against a local `gem server`, this will get an instance of a parsed document, and allow me to extract nodes and their parameters:

```
page = agent.get('http://0.0.0.0:8808/')
page.at('a')
```

If I want the text content of that node:

```
page.at('a').text
# => "abstract"
```

In your case, use `page.at('td[colspan="3"]').text` to get the contents.